# How do I write this special attributes with XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, xml

I tried multiple times to write the following XML node with the XmlWriter class, but I don't get it ;(

```
<document xmlns="abc:def-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="abc:def-org:v3 test.xsd">
```

Can someone help me?
Kind regards

Comment: Do you **need** to use `XmlWriter` ? This would be a lot simpler with any of `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, or `XmlSerializer`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(...))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("document", "abc:def-org:v3");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "abc:def-org:v3 test.xsd");
    // ...
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Note in particular that when we add `schemaLocation`, we don't add `xsi:schemaLocation`, but rather we add "`schemaLocation` in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace", and `XmlWriter` maps this to `xsi`. If you always talk in terms of namespaces rather than prefixes, you won't have any nasty surprises when you change prefix.